# duplicate values in new csv file

Tags: python, csv

I'm working on a program and want to write my result into a comma separated file, like a CSV.

```
 new_throughput =[]
 self.t._interval = 2
 self.f = open("output.%s.csv"%postfix, "w")
 self.f.write("time, Byte_Count, Throughput \n")
 cur_throughput = stat.byte_count  
 t_put.append(cur_throughput)
 b_count = (cur_throughput/131072.0) #calculating bits
 b_count_list.append(b_count)
 L = [y-x for x,y in zip(b_count_list, b_count_list[1:])] #subtracting current value - previous, saves value into list
 for i in L:    
     new_throughput.append(i/self.t._interval)                                                                                                               
     self.f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s \n"%(self.experiment, b_count, b_count_list,new_throughput)) #write to file
```

when running this code i get this in my CSV file 
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaTgM.png).
It somehow prints out the previous value every time.

What I want is new row for each new line:

```
time , byte_count, throughput  
20181117013759,0.0,0.0  
20181117013759,14.3157348633,7.157867431640625  
0181117013759,53.5484619141,, 19.616363525390625
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a working minimal example, but your last line should refer to the last member of each list, not the whole list. Something like this:

```
 self.f.write("%s,%s,%s,%s \n"%(self.experiment, b_count, b_count_list[-1],new_throughput[-1])) #write to file
```

Edit: ...although if you want this simple solution to work, then you should initialize the lists with one initial value, e.g. `[0]`, otherwise you'd get a "list index out of range error" at the first iteration according to your output.